# Induced Subgraphs on Digraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a concept of induced subgraphs for directed graphs? I would intuitively think it is nearly the same as for undirected graphs.

I was just thinking that it would be a subset of the vertices such that all arcs from the original graph from one vertex in the subset to another in the subset exists in the induced subgraph edge set.

Comment: Why? Can you explain it bit more, it quiet complicated for me to understand why you think like that.

Comment: I think I was overthinking it. You just delete vertices and all the edges it sends and all the edges pointing to the vertex!

Comment: I don't know graph theory much, so sorry, can you explain that to me properly, may be the weight argument works. I am not sure though.

Comment: Yes. One uses the same definition. Every edge of the bigger graph that has has its endvertices in the subgraph already lies in the subgraph.